# Is it biblical to ask God a question, and he gives the answer to someone else and not you?

Tags: prayer, satan, hindered-prayer

My dad is a Christian but I’m not sure that he is really talking to and hearing from God like he claims. My mom always tells him all about what she prays during her quiet time (which even though they are one, is this even right?) anyways, she had a big decision to make and prayed and asked God what to do. She didn’t hear an immediate response and she told dad that she had just asked God. Well, a few hours later dad says he prayed about it twice and he felt like God told him the answer. So, my mom made her decision, only based on what dad had told her, and now she doesn’t feel peaceful about the decision. Dad has done this several times, where he gets someone else’s answer from God, instead of them hearing it themselves. And it always just so happens to be the thing that dad WANTED before “praying”. Dad has done this with me as well, (multiple times) and I never feel peaceful about it. Is this biblical? Could he be hearing from himself or possibly satan or maybe just lying about it to us? Please help!

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._